# The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) Fraction, Fraction

Tags: java, objeto

me esta dando error una linea de codigo (16) donde me dice: `The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) Fraction, Fraction` por qué puede pasar esto? mi codigo es:

```
public class RekursionKlassen {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fraction[] arr={(new Fraction(2,2)),(new Fraction(3,3)),(new Fraction(4,4)),(new Fraction(5,5)),(new Fraction(6,6)) };
        int i = 4;
        System.out.print(maximum(arr,i));
    }
    public static Fraction maximum(Fraction[]arr,int i) {
        if( i<0 || i >=arr.length) {
            throw new RuntimeException(); 
        }
        else {
            if( i == 0) {
                return arr[0];
            } else {
                if(arr[i] > maximum(arr,i-1)) { //aqui me sale el error
                    return arr[i];
                }else {
                    return maximum(arr,i-1);
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Para comparar con > tendrías que comparar valores numéricos, por ejemplo el valor double obtenido de esa fracción. Otra opción es comparar dos fracciones con maxFraction, que da como resultado la fracción de mayor valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando `maxFraction` puedes obtener el valor de la fracción mayor al comparar dos fracciones.

Reemplazaría

```
if(arr[i] > maximum(arr,i-1)) { //aqui me sale el error
                        return arr[i];
                    }else {
                        return maximum(arr,i-1);
                    }
```

Por

```
Fraction res = maxFraction(arr[i], maximum(arr,i-1));
return res;
```

Puedes ver más info [aquí](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-compare-two-fractions/).

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ayudó mucho tu respuesta.